# onmouseover event on each datatable's row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I need to make each row of the checkbox column launch an event hover and pass the an element's detail on the javascript method so I can do something with it

```
<p:dataTable    
        rows="#{bean.list.size()}"
        value="#{bean.lista}" 
        var="variable"
        selection="#{bean.listSelected}">

        <p:column headerText="" selectionMode="multiple"> 
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="" id="id_1" filterBy="#{varriable}" >                                 
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

So I need to do something like this

```
<p:column headerText="" selectionMode="multiple" onmouseover=someMethod(#{varriable.abc})>
```

Is there any Way to make it happen?

Comment: Do you need `variable.abc` or would `variable` be enough? I'd start by investigating whether you can use a plain jquery eventhandler on the `td` that is rendered by the column.

Comment: if I can retrieve the `abc` 's value from `variable`inside the javascript method it will be ok by passing `variable`as parameter

Comment: If that would be possible easily I would not have asked... ;-)... If `abc` is not in any other colum and you actually need it, I'd check if you can use a passtrough attribute on the column tag which contains `#{variable.abc}`and read that in the eventhandler...

Comment: But effectively you need eventhandlers on a CELL do you? Not a row

Comment: I actually need the event in the whole row, it's easier in the second column because I can put a div inside but this is not the case of the first column of checkbox